# Register as facebook developer without using phone number

Tags: facebook

I needed to register as a facebook developer to use facebook sdk.
facebook asked me for phone number to do it. 
I'm from Myanmar(Burma) so I used myanmar mobile number in order to receive the confrimation code. I got this error from facebook:
"Contact point error: Sorry, we have already tried texting multiple codes and they all seem to have failed. Please click here to get help."

Is there's a way to register for facebook developer without using phone number?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't code related; you're trying to register a developer with a 3rd party platform.

Comment: Then request it be moved, not closed. It is a legitimate question and terrible situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of this writing you have two options for verifying your account:

- Text/call to a phone number to receive a verification code

  - Go to your profile, edit it and add a phone number; Once you save a Verify link will appear next to it, use that to verify your account.
- Add a credit card to your account

  - Settings → Payments → Payment Methods → Manage. Once you add a valid CC your account will be considered verified.

Note that *you do not* have to keep your CC on your account once your account is verified; Not sure about phone number as that never worked for me either (either method).

Source (and links): https://www.facebook.com/help/167551763306531